# Relation between the 3D and the 2D coefficients of diffusion

Tags: diffusion, brownian-motion

I am considering a diffusive process in 2D with a given diffusion coefficient $D_2$ and I want to estimate the the 3D diffusion coefficient $D_3$ considering that the $(x,y)$ positions of the particle are just the projections of its 3D movement.

The process is isotropic, so what I have done is to consider

$$\langle x^2 + y^2 \rangle = 2 \langle x^2 \rangle = 2D_2t$$
$$\langle x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \rangle = 3 \langle x^2 \rangle = 2 D_3 t $$

Where I have used that the process is isotropic and diffusive. From here I get that:

$$D_3 = \frac{3}{2} D_2$$

Am I right? How can I estimate the 3D diffusive behaviour of a particle knowing its 2D diffusive behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are given a 2D diffusion profile and you want to write a 3D simulator so that the result gives similar 2D profile in a cut plane, I think you are right.

On the other hand, if you are comparing a 3D and pseudo-2D case, maybe you want to use the same diffusivity as they have the same physics. For 3D, it is just a regular 3D, e.g. the initial profile is a group of particles in a small sphere and then diffuse. For pseudo-2D, it is still 3D but the 3rd dimension is so small that the concentration of the particle is essentially uniform in that dimension (so no diffusion in 3rd dimension, and mathematically this is a 2D problem) and you are seeing only 2D profile evolution as a function of time.